# Parse array in Json with nodeJs

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

This is my json:

```
{

    "xuid":****************,
    "state":"Online",
    "devices":[
        {
            "type":"XboxOne",
            "titles":[
                {
                    "id":750323071,
                    "name":"Accueil",
                    "placement":"Background",
                    "state":"Active",
                    "lastModified":"2018-02-23T17:09:38.4018406Z"
                },
                {
                    "id":1145574011,
                    "activity":{
                        "richPresence":"Dans un salon priv\u00e9"
                    },
                    "name":"Titanfall\u2122 2",
                    "placement":"Full",
                    "state":"Active",
                    "lastModified":"2018-02-23T17:09:38.4018406Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

I would like to recover the value: `devices->titles->1->activity->richPresence`
This is my code with nodeJs:

```
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        var xbJson = JSON.parse(body);          
        console.log(xbJson.devices.titles[1]['name'])
    }
}
```

My error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/home/atmoner/Bureau/xboxlive/test.js:16:40)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/atmoner/Bureau/xboxlive/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/atmoner/Bureau/xboxlive/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/atmoner/Bureau/xboxlive/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
```

I guess the problem comes from the array in a json and I can not move further.
It may sound simple but I need some help.
Thank you!...

Comment: Wouldn't it be `console.log(xbJson.devices[0].titles[1]['name'])` as `devices` is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
console.log(xbJson.devices[0].titles[1]['name'])
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` The problem comes after `[1]` When i try this, it work: `console.log(xbJson.devices[0].titles)` result: https://i.imgur.com/CVmX0Zc.jpg

Comment: devices is an array of length 1,and it contains one object i.e. accessible by devices[0].Instead of writing devices,you need to write devices[0].When you write devices.titles[1] it can't find it because devices is an array,not object.Thus titles remain undefined in your case.

Comment: @Julien your screenshot shows that the titles array only contains one element, which is different from the JSON provided in your post. You probably want `titles[0]`, not `titles[1]` in that case. But I would also recommend not hard coding these values either if your titles array can potentially be multiple lengths.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain & Ayan My bad!! Indeed, my console was only on the main acch .... so he could not recover something that does not exist! By launching a game, I can recover the good value ... I will opt for a foreach and thus recover all the elements in a loop ... Thank you very much for your help !!